# data members are not initialized even though they are

Tags: php

I am a Java programmer trying to code in PHP and I am a little confused. I am using Netbeans as my IDE and there are warning messages for $host, $user, $pass and $db saying that these data members are not initialized even though they are.

```
class Database {

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "MYDATABASE";
    private $pass = "MYPASSWORD";
    private $db = "MYDATABASE";

    private $con = null;

    function connect() {
        $con = pg_connect("host=$this->$host dbname=$this->$db user=$this->$user password=$this->$pass")
                or die("Could not connect to server\n");
    }

    function disconnect() {
        pg_close($this->$con);
    }
}
```

When I run the script using the code below I get the following error message

```
<?php

require_once "./helpers/Database.php";
$database = new Database();
$database->connect();
?>
```

"PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Database could not be converted to string in /var/www/MYSITE/helpers/Database.php on line 13"

Comment: `$this->$host` <--- what's this?

Comment: And `$this->$db`, `$this->$user`...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for using [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) is wrong, it should be `$this->foobar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"host={$this->$host}..."
```

You have two problems.

The first (the reason for the error), is that you do not have the {braces}.  This means PHP is trying to evaluate "$this" as a string, then the string literal "->", then "$host" as a string.  Using {braces} is good practice, but not strictly necessary if the second problem is corrected.

The second problem is you are using the "$host" variable, when you want the "host" property of the Database object.  With the $ there, it says, evaluate the $host variable ("localhost"), then lookup the "localhost" property of the database object (for which there is none).  By leaving the $ out, you reference the "host" object property instead of the property named by the $host variable.

Comment: The good alternative also is to use `sprintf()`

Answer (score 0):

This creates a connection string that you can use to pass into `pg_connect()`:

```
$dsn = sprintf("host='%s' dbname='%s' user='%s' password='%s'",
    addcslashes($this->host, "\\'"),
    addcslashes($this->db, "\\'"),
    addcslashes($this->user, "\\'"),
    addcslashes($this->pass, "\\'")
);
```

It disambiguates expressions such as `$this->host` inside a double quoted string and encapsulates each parameter in single quotes so that it supports spaces or empty values.